# The direction of steepest descent is unique

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

If $f$ is a proper convex function and $x$ is in the interior of the  domain of $f$, how would one go about proving that the direction of steepest descent at $x$ is unique?

Intuitively, I get it, but don't know how one would prove this rigorously.

Comment: How do you define the direction of steepest descent?